# How to invoke Pyscripter debugger

Tags: python, debug

Using pythonwin, you can invoke the debugger by pywin.debugger.brk()

Can you somehow do the same thing with pyscripter? The advantage of this method is that your code runs at normal speed until the debugger is invoked while running computationally intensive code in the debugger is rather slow.

Comment: Perhaps this should be in stack overflow but I saw people attacking the guy for asking similar IDE specific question.

Comment: Went back to Pywin for now. I should look into 3rd party debugger like IDLE or Wing IDE.